# My 14 yr old Shepherd husky mix does not test positive for Cushings Disease...so now what!

Tags: dogs, health

He has all the classic systems, had major diarrhea for 8 days, was in vets on iv for 5 of those days.

Now has excessive thirst, frequent urine, sway walking, weak back legs, eats lots of protein ....will not touch dog food or starches.  Hair is falling out with the scab effect, been treated several meds for that and won't improve...

No uti, not cushings...blood is normal range, I'm  so frustrated.

Comment: Can you post bloodwork results?

Comment: What does your vet suppose?